# How to restore InnoDB from files

Tags: innodb, backup, files

here is the situation I fu*d up my mysql setup, before I did that I copied entire `/var/lib/mysql` directory to another location. Now fresh installation of mysql is back and I cannot restore my files.

If I simply drop files back to `/var/lib/mysql`, things get wired, for example I can see table names from mysql cli, when I try `show tables` but when I try to access a table I get message

> Table '*' doesn't exist

Now this problems seems pretty common, I have searched all over Google and I understand that we cannot move InnoDB files just like that. There is InnoDB table counter and other other mystical stuff for me.

But one thing I cannot understand is I have all files that should contain all information about database, I'm talking about `mysql/` directory inside `/var/lib/`, why is it so hard to recover database from that, and also is there any place other than `/var/lib/mysql/` where InnoDB keeps information about database?